# PHP Regex and enter problem

Tags: php, regex, enter

**Code**

---

```
(preg_match_all("#\[level-(.+)-\](.+?)\[/level\]#", $string, $matches)
```

**Problem**

---

if I assign any value to `$string` with enter, my regex doesn't work.

**Example:**

```
//This doesn't work
$string = '[level-0-]This is a 
test[/level]';
//This works
$string = '[level-0-]This is a test[/level]';
```

**What I Want**

---

I would like my regex to work no matter what characters between (enter, etc..).

I will be glad if anyone could help me out with this one. I still didn't dig into regex yet so I'm not that good with it :(

Comment: what does "regex doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Could you perhaps be a bit clearer about what portion[s] of the string you want the regex to match?

Comment: @Andrea; Doesn't work means, regex fails, returns no values. I thought it was clear enough (checking the answers, I believe it was).

Comment: @Isiscode: My problem wasn't about matching directly. It was just as I wrote in example code, when I go to new line regex was turning FALSE, returning no values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need the **DOTALL** flag `/s` in your regex. This allows the dot `.` to match any character, including linebreaks (which it doesn't do per default).

```
preg_match_all("#\[level-(.+)-\](.+?)\[/level\]#s", ....
```

See also the PCRE flags list http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to get regex to treat its input as a single line by adding the /s flag to your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use `s` Pattern Modifier:

If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. (Ref: [Possible modifiers in regex patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
(preg_match_all("#\[level-(.+)-\](.+?)(\b)*(.+?)*\[/level\]#", $string, $matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Test[.|\n]is[.|\n]a[.|\n]test"` this might work